# EDIT: A later new lineWidth is overriding a previous lineWidth for isPointInStroke

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a have a line's that are drawn in a varias directions. I save the path and then check if I hover over the point:

How the line is made:

```
        let path = new Path2D();            
        ctx.lineWidth = 20; // this doesn't seem to affect the hitbox of the liine
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        path.moveTo(start.x + (width / 2), start.y);
        path.lineTo(start.x + (width / 2) + linePadding, start.y);
        path.lineTo(mid, start.y);
        path.lineTo(mid, end.y);
        path.lineTo(end.x - (width / 2) - linePadding, end.y);
        ctx.stroke(path);
        ctx.closePath();
```

when I check to see if I hit the path:

```
                path_Arrows.some(element => {
                    if (ctx.isPointInStroke(element.path, mouseLocation.x, mouseLocation.y)) {
```

it doesn't seem to detect the whole stroke, just the tiny little stroke. Changing the `lineWidth` does change the line visually, but not the `isPointInStroke`. Adjusting the `mouseLocation.x, mouseLocation.y` to adjust for a hitbox range *is* technically possible, but because these lines are so dynamic and procedural it would be incredibly difficult to account for each potential location (unless I'm thinking of this wrong).

I've also considered changing mainting a line the way I do with the desired lineWidth (like 5) and then just draw rectangles with 0 alphas from the points they move and check `isPointInPath`.

EDIT:

The issue comes from an function that I use to create a shape, and then within the function I check if I need to draw a line from that shape and if I do I draw the line, and then continue out the drawing the shape.

For example:

```
drawLine(ctx, from, to);

let box = new Path2D();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle  = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
box.rect(x, y, rWidth, rHeight);
ctx.fill(box);

ctx.strokeRect(x, y, rWidth, rHeight);
ctx.closePath();
```

The line is created fairly similar to how I displayed it before the edit within `drawLine()`, and then continue withdrawing the box after the call. Setting the lineWidth & color within `drawLine()` is visually correct, and the `lineWidth` set within the box is also correct in color and size.

Although the isPointInStroke is detecting the size of the line set within box, not within `drawLine()`.

I can increase the line width to a large amount, such as 50, and the stroke of the box is increased, the stroke of the line **are not**, but it is detecting catching the point as if it was that huge.

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctx.isPointInStroke()` **will** use the current `lineWidth` value to set the stroke's hit-box. Double check it's still set to the correct value when you call it.
Also beware it will even be affected by the current transformation matrix.

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

const path = new Path2D();
path.moveTo( 10, 10 );
path.lineTo( 80, 10 );
path.lineTo( 80, 50 );
path.lineTo( 30, 50 );
path.lineTo( 10, 30 );

ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.stroke(path);

ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.stroke( path );

function isOverStroke( line_width, x, y ) {
  ctx.lineWidth = line_width;
  return ctx.isPointInStroke( path, x, y );
}

onmousemove = (evt) => {
  const rect = ctx.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
  
  let hovered_color = "transparent";
  if( isOverStroke( 2, x, y ) ) {
    hovered_color = "red";
  }
  else if( isOverStroke( 20, x, y ) ) {
    hovered_color = "green";
  }
  color_logger.style.backgroundColor = hovered_color;
};
```

```css
#color_logger {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="150"></canvas>
<div id="color_logger"></div>
```

Comment: I actually made a test similar to this, and it seems that somewhere else for somereason my stroke is being registered as 1px line, and I have no idea where or how even though the visual is drawn much larger. Currently debugging down to sort out where this is coming from.

Comment: Could be changing the size of your canvas (`width` or `height`) this will reset every properties of your context

Comment: I found it.. 

I have an element, I'll edit my question because this raises a new problem I don't understand why it's happening.

Comment: That edit might actually be better as its own question. Also, could you try to set up an [MCVE] showing exactly how you do the calls? From here it's unclear why you'd expect the lineWidth to be anything else than `1` since it's apparently the last value you did set it to.